# Display new content on hover or click

Tags: css, html, menu

I would like my `<nav>` menu to display new content on the page. For example, my menu is below the center of the page which contains a big .png design. I'd like that when you click a link, it doesn't load another page, but displays new content on the page, with a basic animation. Like if clicking the link pulled the new content out of the `<nav>`.

Is it possible to do this with only HTML5 and CSS ?

Comment: fiddle or display your code..

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Now you may start writing the code.

Comment: Hi @NabeelSheikh, thanks for your quick answer. There it is : http://jsfiddle.net/E4aSs/ . Of course, you can't see the images because I'm working with local files for now.

Comment: You can make it easier to explain by providing some of your code. A snippet from the html page where the navigation is present (or a similar basic example relevant enough) will certainly improve the quality of the question

Comment: Hi @IvayloSlavov, i just did in my first comment :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be easy enough with jQuery to hook at the click event of the navigation links. So if you have:

```
<a id="navigationLink1" > Some Navigation Item </a>
```

you might link a click-handler like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var linkClickHandler = function() {
        // your code with the animation and etc
    };

    $('#navigationLink1').hover(linkClickHandler);
    $('#navigationLink1').click(linkClickHandler);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! Unfortunately I only know HTML and CSS. I don't understand the code you wrote.

Comment: This is javascript. It requres you to have the jQuery library added to your page in order to ineract with dom elements. In general, it is a good and necessary addition to get a glimpse at javacript, as it is essential part of the today's web development

Comment: Ok, so there is no way to do it with only HTML and CSS. I'm still learning, and will definitely go through JS later when i'll be comfortable with HTML and CSS. I will keep your answer in a file anyways, it will be useful for sure. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: As suits you best. Some things cannot be achieved merely by html and css, so I hope you find js easy enough. I recommend you take a look at jquery as it simplifies most of the javascript usage and will certainly help you with custom front-end effects and dom interaction.